# lgi core module fails to load within lua

Tags: lua, awesome-wm

Disclaimer: I do not know that much about Lua, so there might be a error on my part. Nonetheless it's interesting and awesomewm requires it.

Recently I installed awesomeWm and it run perfectly. Afterwards I messed a bit around with the rc.lua and broke it. For some reason (I do not know why) I logged then out and then I couldn't log back it. I figured, if I would revert the rc.lua to the default one included in `/etc/xdg/awesome/` would work, but for some reason it wouldn't.

Then I tried to start awesome with the "debugging" window as described [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/awesome#Troubleshooting). For some reason a lot of packages were missing now and awesome wouldn't even start. I do not know how it worked it the first place... Afterwards I installed libaries including Image and Lgi with `luarocks` and I managed to adapt the paths in `LUA_PATH` so lua would find the needed libaries.

While this, I found out, I can check if it works by simply starting lua and executing `require('lgi')`, but this fails now with the error `/home/$user/.luarocks/lib/lua/5.2/lgi/corelgilua51.so:1: unexpected symbol near char(127)`

I searched for a solution close to a good day and I am really out of ideas. Any help really needed and appreciated.

Comment: What does `file /home/$user/.luarocks/lib/lua/5.2/lgi/corelgilua51.so` say?

Comment: `ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=324e5a1216f8219e4a3c515835770833dd277b95, not stripped`

Comment: And did you point `LUA_PATH` at that directory? Instead of pointing `LUA_CPATH` there?

Comment: `LUA_PATH` points there. Just for testing I installed awesome wm in a vm and tested it (it works) tried to copy the library over and use that, but still the same error. It seems the error is not actually not there...

Comment: `LUA_PATH` == lua modules. `LUA_CPATH` == C modules.

Comment: Thank you, good to know, but it finds the library, it just throws an error.

Comment: Yes, because it expects it to be a lua module and not C. It is trying to load it incorrectly. Use the right `LUA_PATH`/`LUA_CPATH` and see if that fixes things.

Comment: That fixed it. Than you really much. I appreciate your patience with, in the aftermath, really noobish mistake, but I didn't work with lua before and it worked before, so I had no idea where to really look.